# JPA Specification and null parameter in .where clause

Tags: jpa, null, spring-data-jpa, specification-pattern

I wrote two Specifications which return null if their parameter is null.

```
public static Specification<Prodotto> getProdottoByLineaSpec (String linea) {

        if (linea != null) {
            return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                return criteriaBuilder.like((root.join("linea")).get("nome"), "%"+linea+"%");
            };
        }
        else return null;
    }

public static Specification<Prodotto> getProdottoByIngSpec (String ing) {

        if (ing != null) {
            return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
                return criteriaBuilder.like(((root.join("listaQuoteIng")).join("ing")).get("nome"), "%"+ing+"%");
            };
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

Then I created a third one that combines the previous ones with an `and` operator inside a `where` clause:

```
public static Specification<Prodotto> getProdottoByMainTraits (String linea, String ing) {

        return Specification.where(getProdottoByLineaSpec(linea).and(getProdottoByIngSpec(ing)));
    }
```

Now, that's the funny part:

- If `ByLinea` returns `null`, i get a `nullPointerException` from `checkPackageAccess` when resolving the `where` clause.
- If `ByIng` returns `null`, it just gets ignored (like it should be) and the query matches just the other predicate.
- If I switch the two predicates, putting `ByIng` as the first one and then `ByLinea` inside the `where` clause, everything works in every combination.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a good practice to avoid returning `null` from methods.

You can use  `criteriaBuilder`.[conjunction()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#conjunction--) to ignore `null` parameter `Specification`. It generates always `true` `Predicate`. There is an opposite method `criteriaBuilder`.[disjunction()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#disjunction--)

```
public static Specification<Prodotto> getProdottoByLineaSpec (String linea) {
                        
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        if (linea == null) {                 
            return criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
        }

        return criteriaBuilder.like(
                 (root.join("linea")).get("nome"), 
                 "%" + linea + "%"
        );            
    }
}
```

P.S. You get `NullPointerException` if first `Specification` is `null` trying to access a method `and`.
To be clear it looks like this

```
Specification.where(null.and(getProdottoByIngSpec(ing)));
```

But if only second `Specification` is `null` this one works

```
Specification.where(getProdottoByLineaSpec(linea).and(null));
```

because [and](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html#and-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-) method parameter can be `null`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't know those methods. It actually works, you just got to call the lambda function inside else block
`else return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.conjunction();`
I upvote your answer, but wait to mark it as solution, because it doesn't explain why my original structure got no problem if I switch predicates order inside where clause.

Comment: It is my fault in else block. I wrote the code using phone. I have edited the answer.

Comment: The answer also contains `NullPointerException` cause explanation

Comment: Yesterday I was experiencing this strange behaviour:
if I set ByIng as first predicate, and make it return null, i didn't get the problem!
That was the thing that I couldn't understand. Now I just retried, and actually it throws the expected exception. Probably yesterday was tired, and made some mistake.

Thean as a general rule, is it always better to make a Specification return conjunction/disjunction instead of null, when you want it to be nullable?

Comment: Yes. Or you should handle every possible nulls. But this approach is more error prone

Comment: Keep it in mind that every conjunction and disjunction add extra where clause in sql statement. For conjunction it looks this way 1=1.

Comment: Didn't think about that... perhaps this different approach adds overhead on the service, but eases workload on DB. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210438/6350583
What do you think?

Comment: I can opt for this approach only for private methods. But for external api I try to avoid returning null. Conjunction and disjunction clauses do not cause any workload. They are used as predicates markers.

Comment: Didn't you wrote that conjunction adds an extra where clause to query?

Comment: Yes, but clauses like 1=1 cost nothing

Comment: Perfect. I marked your answer as solution. Thanks a lot.